# wso2is role like claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an wso2is with AD as a data store
I'm trying to provide SP with claim that contents less data (cap is at 4k) but my "role" claim is too big for general users. Is there any way to create additional "role" like claim that could be filtered with prefix for example? Like only ad groups with name asd-* are included in this claim.

Comment: Regarding to your question I understood that you want to create a claim which contains the groups with asd-* name. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is what I’m looking for.